# Language identification (British and US English)

Tags: python, text, analysis

I've played around with some of the language identification packages in Python and although they very successfully differentiate general languages, they fail to differentiate  British English and American English. Has anyone come across a technique (in Python) that can be used to identify this difference?

Comment: `d = {'color': 'American', 'colour': 'Redcoat'}` :)

Comment: try http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to check for instances of consonant + "or"/"our", something like:

```
import re

txt="honor"

re_american = re.compile(".*?[bcdfghjklmnptv](o)(r)",re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
re_british = re.compile(".*?[bcdfghjklmnptv](o)(u)(r)",re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)

b = re_british.search(txt)
a = re_american.search(txt)

if b: print "British"
elif a: print "American"
```

Comment: It's a bit simplistic; American English has "four", for example.